# Change speaker for webrtc calls on mobile device using the browser

Tags: android, ios, safari, stream, webrtc

What I am trying to achieve:
 1. When initiating a call via webrtc, the default speaker should be the ear speaker not the loudspeaker
 2. I need a way to switch between loud and ear speakers while on call(I guess there is an event?)

What I tried so far:
 1. Calling `navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()` to see what "audiooutput" devices I will get.
It shows different devices on different devices(expected result). The strange thing is that on Mobile IOS I get no such devices, although I get voice from the loud speaker... On android devices I get only one "audiooutput"
 2. Made a research for possible solutions but couldn`t find any...

Any help will be much appreciated!!!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find a solution?